# Matlab Multidimensional Arrays with string + Exporting to Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, multidimensional-array, xls

i have a code that works on all files in folder and analyise it and come then export results into excel sheet.

My question is, by the end i alot of excel sheets and i need to combine them all together (i also need them separate) so i do this manualy and its really painfull and time wasting !

So i want to ask is there a way to create an array to save the results of each analysis my code process and export all at the end to one excel file.

Example of my code Workflow:
Read files in current dir
Open files one by one.
Do math equations and get results into 2 arrays amp[] signal[] (both are equal in size)
Export results into Excel using

```
xlswrite([b '.xls'],[amp' signal'],1);%%b=file name (example.avi ==> example.avi.xls)
```

And so on.

So i want to save the results after that to array with the filename and at the end past all into 1 excel sheet with the file name on top of each column :)

I dont know why i'm having a brain block on how to do it !

Thanks alot for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xlswrite supports that you give a start point or range where you want to put your data. See [Xlswrite](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html).

You can quickly calculate the column name using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15748-excel-column-number-to-column-name).

But you must be aware that excel only supports 255 columns and 1024 rows in a sheet. This happened often to me and then one gets a very uninformative error.